# Javascript Filter Objects in Array and return Property of Object in Array of Object in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, filter

Im trying to Filter this Array:

```
var Zimmer = [{"Name":"F02A","Group":"Office","Devices":[
    {"Name":"F02A-1313.01","Device":"00265BE98E8C53","Type":"HmIP-WTH-B"},
    {"Name":"F02A-1315.03","Device":"00201BE9A13271","Type":"HmIP-eTRV-B"},
    {"Name":"F02A-1354.01","Device":"00119A499C1313","Type":"HmIP-eTRV-C"}
]},
{"Name":"F1","Group":"Office","Devices":[
    {"Name":"F1-1315.04","Device":"00201BE9A1381B","Type":"HmIP-eTRV-B"}
]},
{"Name":"F2","Group":"Klassenzimmer","Devices":[
    {"Name":"F2-1315.02","Device":"00201BE9A137E5","Type":"HmIP-eTRV-B"}
]},
{"Name":"F6","Group":"Office","Devices":[
    {"Name":"F6-1315.01","Device":"00201BE9A13290","Type":"HmIP-eTRV-B"}
]}]
```

And I want to output every Device with the Name F02A.
example: 00265BE98E8C53 and than second output 00201BE9A13271.

For that I wrote the code

```
msg.payload = Zimmer.forEach(element => element.filter(name => name.Name = "F02A"));
```

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and check if the name starts with the wanted part.

```js
const
    zimmer = [{ Name: "F02A", Group: "Office", Devices: [{ Name: "F02A-1313.01", Device: "00265BE98E8C53", Type: "HmIP-WTH-B" }, { Name: "F02A-1315.03", Device: "00201BE9A13271", Type: "HmIP-eTRV-B" }, { Name: "F02A-1354.01", Device: "00119A499C1313", Type: "HmIP-eTRV-C" }] }, { Name: "F1", Group: "Office", Devices: [{ Name: "F1-1315.04", Device: "00201BE9A1381B", Type: "HmIP-eTRV-B" }] }, { Name: "F2", Group: "Klassenzimmer", Devices: [{ Name: "F2-1315.02", Device: "00201BE9A137E5", Type: "HmIP-eTRV-B" }] }, { Name: "F6", Group: "Office", Devices: [{ Name: "F6-1315.01", Device: "00201BE9A13290", Type: "HmIP-eTRV-B" }] }],
    result = zimmer.flatMap(({ Devices }) =>
        Devices.flatMap(({ Name, Device }) => Name.startsWith('F02A') ? Device : [])
    );
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method to loop through your array then check condition(check 'Name' is matched) each array, if your condition match then use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to make your devices to array, then concat to output

```
Zimmer.reduce((acc,data)=>{
    if(data.Name === "F02A"){
        acc = acc.concat(data.Devices.map((device)=>device.Device))
    }
    return acc
},[])

// output: ["00265BE98E8C53", "00201BE9A13271", "00119A499C1313"]
```